# What is this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str' and how do i fix it

Tags: python

I am writing a Python 2.7 script that takes a URL and checks if the server is responding if the server is online then it takes a file and combines it with the server address and then checks if the file is on the server depending on the results then it attempts to download the file the code is below.

If someone could explain to me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it along with how the error occurred i would appreciate it.

The downloading code comes from pythonforbeginners.com
I have tried asking this on StackOverflow and just got answers basically telling me to figure it out for myself and I got blocked from asking questions hopefully someone here can help me.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
Server = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
File = '/Download.txt'
URL = Server + File
if URL.getcode() == 200:
    Response = urllib2.urlopen(Server)
    Write = open(file, "w")
    Write.write(response.read())
    Write.close()
else:
    print (' Just Testing')
```

Comment: I would suggest switching to python 3 if possible, don't forget https://pythonclock.org/  (python 2's EOL clock)

Comment: Yeah i would however i learned Python 2.7 and for some reason i really prefer it over 3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing your variables. "Server" is not the URL string. It's an instance of urllib2 that is there for handy usage.

```
site      = "https://www.example.com"
file_path = site + "/filename.txt"
server    = urllib2.urlopen(site)
response  = urllib2.urlopen(file_path)
print(response.read())
```

Comment: Thank you i will test this out and accept the answer if it is

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0eX2RK1j you solved that error however the Pastebin paste is the traceback of the new one

Comment: A 404 Not Found error has nothing to do with your Python code. Remember also that Py2 is deprecated and support will be ended next year. You really should be learning Py3 skills.

Comment: The server is responding from my browser but not from my code and i am going to start learning Python 3